# How do I find the count of distinct records since a certain date (eg: 2018 till current day)?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I just recently started Oracle and I have to essentially find the patients that have been admitted in the hospital at least twice in the given hospital.

Here are the tables I'm working with.

Table Person:-

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON
(
  Person_id         NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY,
  Surname           VARCHAR2(20),
  First_name       VARCHAR2(20),
  Sex                   CHAR(1),
  Birth_date        DATE,
  Street               VARCHAR2(40),
  Town               CHAR(9),
  Postcode          NUMBER(4),
  Next_of_kin    NUMBER(3)
 );

INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (101,'Black','Barry','M','31/12/1959','11 High St.','Cooma',2630,102);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (102,'Black','Mary','F','11/1/1963','11 High St.','Cooma',2630,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (103,'Strathclyde','Albert','M','15/5/1955','3 The Mews','Hawthorne',3171,104);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (104,'Strathclyde','Alice','F','17/7/1955','3 The Mews','Hawthorne',3171,103);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (105,'Green','Gill','F','16/6/1966','124 Main St.','Young',2594,106);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (106,'Green','Graham','M','24/4/1967','124 Main St.','Young',2594,105);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (107,'Gray','Lesley','F','12/9/1972','130 Main St.','Young',2594,109);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (109,'Gray','John','M','14/4/1972','130 Main St.','Young',2594,107);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (110,'Samuelson','Thomas','M','1/1/1964','17 The Mews','Hawthorne',3171,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (111,'Abrahams','Mary','F','15/5/1967','2177A The Esplanade','Ivanhoe',3878,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (112,'Aumann','Monica','F','25/5/1955','29 The Esplanade','Ivanhoe',3878,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (113,'Brown','Melissa','F','8/8/1984','11 East St.','Cooma',2630,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (114,'Napier','Mary','F','1/1/1971','163 New Rd.','Henty',2658,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (115,'Nelson','Nigel','M','2/2/1972','165 Young Rd.','Temora',2666,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (116,'Newman','Olive','F','3/3/1973','21 Olympic Way','Henty',2658,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (117,'Gray','Lesley','M','31/12/1989','130 Andres St.','Young',2594,105);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (118,'Hon','Tasuku','M','13/3/1953','21 Silcon Height','Henty',2658,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (119,'Livingstone','Frank','M','3/3/2003','21 Sun Height','Henty',2658,122);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (120,'Giggle','Frank','M','23/3/1975','21 Albrige Close','Cooma',2630,121);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (121,'Giggle','Felicia','F','3/3/1980','21 Albrige Close','Cooma',2630,120);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (122,'Gigg','Frank Jr','M','13/3/2011','21 Stun Height','Henty',2658,123);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (123,'Gigg','Frances','F','12/12/2005','21 Stun Height','Henty',2658,122);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (124,'Smith','Buddy','M','11/12/1979','101 High St.','Cooma',2630,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (125,'Smith','Maxime','F','31/12/1979','101 High St.','Cooma',2630,124);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (126,'Smith','Issac','M','1/12/2007','101 High St.','Cooma',2630,124);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (127,'Smith','Ronny','M','3/12/2009','101 High St.','Cooma',2630,124);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (128,'Giggle','Fanny','F','3/12/2007','121 Close Rose','Hillo',2330,120);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (129,'Murad','Nadia','F','3/3/2000','121 Close Rose', 'Hillo',2330,130);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (130,'Murad','Tange','M','3/3/1999','7711 Albrige Close','Cooma',2630,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (131,'Rome','Paula','F','23/9/1965','21 Height Close','Cooma',2630,132);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (132,'Rome','Paul','M','13/3/1966','21 Height Close','Cooma',2630,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (133,'Rome','Fay','M','3/3/2017','21 Height Close','Cooma',2630,132);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (134,'Murad','Michelle','F','3/3/2001','1 Height Close','Cooma',2630,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (135,'Trump','Donald','M','13/3/1966','222 White House Avenue','Cooma',2630,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (136,'Trump','Melania','F','3/3/1992','222 White House Avenue','Cooma',2630,135);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (137,'Trump','Baron','M','3/3/2005','222 White House Avenue','Cooma',2630,135);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (138,'Johnson','Boris','M','23/9/1965','10 Downing Street','London',2999,NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (139,'Cordeiro','Wayne','M','3/3/1965','777 Hawaii Close Rose', 'Hillo',7770, NULL);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (140,'Cordeiro','Wayne','M','3/3/1965','777 Hawaii Close Rose', 'Hillo',7770, NULL);
```

Table Admission :-

```
CREATE TABLE ADMISSION (
   Admission_id      NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY,
   Patient_id           NUMBER(3),
   Admission_date  DATE NOT NULL,
   Expected_op      CHAR(3),
   Admitted_by      NUMBER(3),
   Ward_code        CHAR(3),
   Discharge_date  DATE,
FOREIGN KEY (Patient_id) references PERSON(Person_id),
FOREIGN KEY (Expected_op) references OPERATION_TYPE(Op_code),
FOREIGN KEY (Admitted_by) references PERSON(Person_id),
FOREIGN KEY (Ward_code) references WARD(Ward_code)
);
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (205,101,'2/2/2011','HB',114,'P','21/2/2011');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (275,101,'1/9/2010','HY',115,'L','1/11/2010');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (286,101,'3/5/2016','AR',116,'A','3/7/2016');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (303,101,'3/4/2018','LA',125,'F', '13/5/2018'  );
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (298,103,'23/1/2016','TS',114,'L','24/04/2016');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (299,103,'23/3/2016','AP',114,'L','23/4/2016');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (305,103,'23/4/2018','HT',125,'F','29/5/2018');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (321,103,'13/5/2018','AR',125,'F', '23/5/2018' );
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (283,105,'3/12/2015','AR',116,'A','5/12/2015');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (278,105,'1/1/2011','HB',115,'P','30/1/2011');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (307,105,'3/4/2018','TS',125,'F',  '13/5/2018');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (276,106,'24/8/2010','LA',114,'P','15/9/2010');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (287,106,'3/5/2016','AP',114,'A','3/6/2016');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (274,109,'1/9/2010','AP',114,'P','9/9/2010');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (288,109,'23/5/2016','LO',114,'F','3/07/2016');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (301,112,'13/4/2018','AP',125,'F','16/4/2018');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (304,112,'23/4/2019','LO',114,'L','23/5/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (279,113,'3/9/2010','TS',115,'F','10/9/2010');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (284,113,'3/12/2015','HY',116,'A','03/01/2016');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (285,113,'3/5/2016','HT',116,'A','3/6/2016');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (300,113,'23/4/2018','AR',114,'L','25/6/2018');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (306,113,'13/8/2018','AP',125,'L', '13/9/2018');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (277,114,'20/9/2010','AP',115,'P','30/9/2010');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (289,115,'11/4/2016','TS',114,'L','3/6/2016');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (290,115,'5/5/2016','LO',114,'L','3/06/2016');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (308,115,'23/3/2018','AR',114,'L','25/3/2018');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (280,117,'3/9/2010','AP',115,'F','25/9/2010');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (281,117,'3/9/2014','HB',116,'A','21/9/2014');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (282,117,'3/12/2015','LA',116,'A','4/12/2015');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (309,126,'23/3/2018','TS',125,'L', '13/5/2018');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (310,127,'13/5/2018','AP',125,'L', '28/5/2018');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (311,124,'3/5/2018','LO',125,'A', '23/5/2018'  );
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (312,127,'21/6/2019','LO',125,'L','22/8/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (313,124,'22/6/2019','AP',125,'A','22/7/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (314,109,'21/6/2019','LO',125,'L','22/7/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (315,126,'12/6/2019','AP',125,'A','22/9/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (316,114,'22/7/2019','HB',125,'A','12/12/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (318,128,'3/5/2019','LA',116,'A','4/6/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (319,129,'23/3/2019','TS',125,'L', '13/4/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (320,130,'3/5/2019','LA',116,'F','4/6/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (328,119,'3/3/2019','TS',115,'N', '3/4/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (322,132,'3/5/2019','LA',116,'A','4/6/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (323,133,'23/3/2019','TS',125,'L', '13/4/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (324,131,'3/5/2018','LA',116,'F','4/5/2018');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (325,118,'3/6/2019','TS',115,'P', '3/7/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (326,102,'3/5/2018','LA',116,'F','4/5/2018');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (327,104,'3/6/2019','TS',115,'P', '3/7/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (339,107,'3/6/2019','TS',115,'P', '3/7/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (329,110,'3/6/2019','TS',115,'P', '3/7/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (330,111,'3/6/2019','TS',115,'P', '3/7/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (331,116,'3/6/2019','TS',115,'P', '3/7/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (332,121,'21/6/2019','TS',125,'L','22/7/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (333,123,'22/7/2019','AP',125,'A','22/9/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (334,134,'21/8/2019','AP',115,'L','22/12/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (335,128,'12/8/2019','AP',115,'A','22/10/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (336,125,'22/7/2018','HB',115,'A','22/8/2018');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (337,120,'21/8/2019','AP',116,'L','22/10/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (338,130,'22/7/2019','AP',125,'N','22/8/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (340,131,'22/8/2019','AP',125,'N','22/10/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (341,122,'22/8/2019','AP',125,'N','22/11/2019');
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (404,112,'23/4/2020','CO',135,'C',NULL);
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (400,113,'23/4/2020','CO',135,'C',NULL);
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (406,115,'13/2/2020','CO',135,'C',NULL);
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (432,121,'21/4/2020','CO',135,'C',NULL);
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (433,123,'22/4/2020','CO',138,'C',NULL);
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (434,134,'21/4/2020','CO',138,'C',NULL);
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (435,128,'12/4/2020','CO',138,'C',NULL);
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (412,127,'21/4/2020','CO',138,'C',NULL);
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (414,109,'21/4/2020','CO',138,'C',NULL);
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (415,126,'12/4/2020','CO',135,'C',NULL);
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (416,114,'22/3/2020','CO',135,'C',NULL);
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (437,120,'21/2/2020','CO',136,'C',NULL);
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (438,130,'22/2/2020','CO',135,'C',NULL);
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (440,131,'22/2/2020','CO',135,'C',NULL);
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (441,122,'22/2/2020','CO',135,'C',NULL);
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (479,118,'3/4/2020','CO',135,'C',NULL);
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (484,111,'3/3/2020','CO',136,'C',NULL);
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (485,116,'3/3/2020','CO',136,'C',NULL);
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (489,119,'11/4/2020','CO',136,'C',NULL);
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (490,139,'11/4/2020','AP',125,'F',NULL);
    INSERT INTO ADMISSION VALUES (491,140,'21/4/2020','AP',138,'F',NULL);
```

I thought using a subquery would work

```
SELECT  DISTINCT p.First_name ||' '|| p.Surname AS "Full Name",
        CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(p.Street,', '),p.Town), p.Postcode) AS "Address", 
        TRUNC((SYSDATE-p.Birth_date)/365.25) AS Age

    FROM PERSON p JOIN ADMISSION a ON p.Person_id = a.Patient_id

    WHERE p.Person_id IN(
        SELECT Patient_id 
            FROM ADMISSION
                GROUP BY Patient_id
                    HAVING (COUNT(Patient_id)>=2)
    )
    AND a.Admission_date>='1/1/2018';
```

but the error I'm coming across is that one of the patients "Barry Black" shows up in the output despite having only been admitted once since 2018.

[Output Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5bFy.png)

Would appreciate any help in this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This query provides you the result in expected format,

```
select first_name ||' '|| surname as full_name, street ||' '|| town  ||' '|| postcode
as address, to_char(birth_date, 'YYYY') - to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') as age
from person;
```

This query provides you the result in where patient admitted at least twice,

```
select first_name ||' '|| surname as full_name, street ||' '|| town  ||' '|| postcode
as address, to_char(birth_date, 'YYYY') - to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') as age
from person where id in
(select id from
(select a.id, count(1) from person p
inner join admission a
on (p.persion_id = a.patient_id)
group by a.id having count(1) >= 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the patient "Barry Black" on account of him being admitted only once since 2018 then we can apply a filter on the group by subquery in order to qualify only patients with multiple visits since 2018.

Note that, by the same criteria, this disqualifies "Gill Green" patient id 105 also who is present in your output results, not just "Barry Black".

```
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY';

SELECT  
   DISTINCT p.First_name ||' '|| p.Surname AS "Full Name",
   CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(p.Street,', '),p.Town), p.Postcode) AS "Address", 
   TRUNC((SYSDATE-p.Birth_date)/365.25) AS Age
FROM PERSON p JOIN ADMISSION a ON p.Person_id = a.Patient_id
WHERE p.Person_id IN (
   SELECT Patient_id 
   FROM ADMISSION
   WHERE Admission_date>='1/1/2018'
   GROUP BY Patient_id
   HAVING (COUNT(Patient_id)>=2)
)
AND a.Admission_date>='1/1/2018'
order by 1,2,3
;
```